# Theme Fallback Performance

Tags: theme, performance

Take for example in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`, in order to remove some of default js/css files, I have declared in `app/design/frontend/{themename}/default/layout/local.xml` removeItems.

Would it be best for me to declare a custom theme `page.xml`? Does Magento identify that a local theme xml file is declared and ignores the default `page.xml` or does Magento look at the custom theme xml file and crosscheck it against the default theme xml file?

The way I currently have it set, by removing items in the `local.xml`, is working, however, logically it seems to hinder performance and I wish to aim for best practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme fallback works like this:
When a file is requested (layout or template) Magento looks first in your theme folder `{package}/{theme}`, then in the theme you set as default `{pacakge}/{default_theme}` and then in `base/default`.  Of course if you have everything in your `{package}/{theme}` folder it will find resources faster, but this comes at a price. If you copy everything in your theme then a future upgrade has a higher chance of failing.
For layouts at least you shouldn't do this. If you have layouts cached, then you shouldn't worry. The layout files are requested once and then they are cached so it's not important where they come from.
For templates you might gain a little speed but I don't think it's worth it if you ever plan to upgrade. You will loose a lot of time to fix your upgrade.

**[EDIT]**
Thanks @JonathanHussey for reminding me this.
Since CE 1.9 Magento supports an infinite fallback mechanism for themes. 
All you have to do is to put a file called `theme.xml` inside your theme in the `etc` folder where you define the parent theme like this:

```
<theme>
    <parent>parent_package/parent_theme</parent>
</theme>
```

The fallback works the same, by reading these files, the only difference being that you are not limited to 3 or 4 fallback levels.

Comment: Might be worth adding a note about infinite theme fallback too in your answer?

Comment: @JonathanHussey Damn. I forgot the new system from 1.9. I will do this immediately.